# Undefined index Notice and Undefined variable Notice

Tags: php

`Notice: Undefined index: post_catagory in /Users/darceymckelvey/Desktop/php/includes/classinsert.php on line 9`

`Notice: Undefined variable: category in /Users/darceymckelvey/Desktop/php/includes/classinsert.php on line 13`

**The code:**

```
<?php
  require_once('classdb.php');

  if(!class_exists('INSERT')){
    class INSERT {
      public function post($postdata){
        global $db;

        $catagory = serialize($postdata['post_catagory']);

        $query = "
                  INSERT INTO posts(post_title, post_content, post_category)
                  VALUES ('$postdata[post_title]', '$postdata[post_content]', '$category')
              ";

        return $db->insert($query);
      }
    }
  }

  $insert = new INSERT;
?>
```

**Issue:**

The outputted result is the `post_title` and `post_content` working but the `post_category` not at all and is left blank.

Comment: Well your `$postdata` array doesn't have an index called `post_category`. Do `print_r($postdata);` to see what you have in your array.

Comment: there's a typo mistake : `$category` in query and your variable `$catagory`, please check it @Darcey Mckelvey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a mistake, there's typo issue in your code, because of which you are not getting category values.

Try this code :

```
<?php
  require_once('classdb.php');

  if(!class_exists('INSERT')){
    class INSERT {
      public function post($postdata){
        global $db;

        $category = serialize($postdata['post_category']);

        $query = "
                  INSERT INTO posts(post_title, post_content, post_category)
                  VALUES ('$postdata['post_title']', '$postdata['post_content']', '$category')
              ";

        return $db->insert($query);
      }
    }
  }

  $insert = new INSERT;
?>
```